# Can I use a TVS diode as an EMI suppressor in long cables?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, tvs, emi-filtering

I'm using a microcontroller to do some things when I press pushbuttons, which are located 20 to 30 meters apart from the MCU.

Should I use TVS diodes as EMI suppressors?

edit - The EMI  I'm mentioning is the usual long distant cable problems, such as induced electricity due to switching events. the sense wire is running closer to the normal main wire network, when I switch on a fan in other room, my MCU seems to trigger the event without actually pushing the button
[TVS diode datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1809192313_ProTek-Devices-SRV05-4-P-T7_C85364.pdf)

Comment: What kind of EMI are you trying to suppress?

Comment: How do you drive the buttons? That's the no 1 concern before anything else. Please clarify and link schematic if needed.

Comment: TVS diodes can be part of the solution, but they aren't a magic bullet

Comment: Define the threat and define the victim.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said, you are getting interference from an external cable into your box, a TVS can be part of the solution, at least to protect the input.

(The fact that you're having the issue at all is a bit troubling - why are low-voltage wires even near any high-current / high voltage stuff? That's a code violation. Time to yell at the electricians!)

But even with the TVS the disturbance will still be making its way into your box and causing an upset (in your case, false triggering) via the signal or the return connection. So, the TVS isn’t enough.

One solution is to use a common-mode suppressor on the cable to block the ESD energy before it hits your box. The common-mode suppressor can be a clamp-on ferrite bead on the cable.

If the noise is really huge, another approach is to use an optoisolator between the button and the box. You will need to supply the opto input side with a low-current power source and return that's isolated from your logic supply (again, through a CM filter or by some other means.)

A similar hack could be done with a relay, with the switch operating the coil and the dry contacts going to your system.

Another possibility is to use an air switch. Then there's zero path for ESD upset.

Comment: it's my hobby project, I've installed them, Space constrains and such issues... no need to shout at poor electricians. anyways, common-mode suppressors are a bit expensive (relatively), speaking about Opto isolators, it sure does seems like a good balance between price and protection. making them high voltage is also make them less susceptible to EMI, right? I'm currently using 5V Logic.

Comment: The point is to break the interference path. Ferrite beads are actually pretty cheap. You can even just use a ferrite toroid and wrap the switch wire a couple of turns around it. The relay idea could work also, and use a bell transformer to power it and the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use these but the real question you need to answer is:

"Will this provide EMI suppression in my application?"

In my opinion the answer is "NO" for this TVI device.  It's purpose is to provide ESD protection NOT to provide EMI suppression in a cable.

So the answer here is: NO, TVS diodes are NOT effective EMI suppressors.

Comment: not effective of won't work? do you think adding them in the I/O of an MCU would do harm?

Comment: Not effective as EMI suppressors.  They will, however, provide ESD protection if properly applied.

Comment: so I should use a ferrite bead?

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not trying to be evasive but you asked whether or not a TVI diode would provide EMI suppression.  That's been answered.  If you now have a different question such as, "here is my circuit and my engineering problem with EMI, how should I go about suppressing it?"  Then please ask another question on that topic.

Comment: Got it! I'm pretty new here, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how this community works and how to do things around here. anyways thanks for advice. good day mate!

Comment: Please see: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, technically ESD is a form of EMI. Really high frequency, jumps where it wants and is usually rerouted to ground or absorbed. Fits the bill! Now, he should specify if it has issues from signals coming in or signals leaking out or whatever. The TVS are a good start however